# creating a summary data frame from long formated data

Tags: r, loops

Following this worked example:

```
case <- c('a','a','a','b','b','c','c','c','c','d','d','e','e')
ID <- c('aa','bb','zz','aa','cc','ee','ff','gg','kk','aa','kk','cc','dd')
score <- c(1,1,3,4,2,3,2,2,1,1,3,3,2)

df1 <- data.frame(case, ID, score)

identifier <- c('aa','bb','ff')
```

For each `unique` *case*, (that is a,b,c,d...), I want to scan the `ID` column and see how often we have an `identifier` value.

- So we look into the 3x `case==a`, then how many times do the `ID` equal `identifier`? (in this case 2 times)
- We then look at 2x `case==b`, and also count how many time `ID` equal `identifier`? (in this case 1 times)
- we do this for all `unique` case's

I have used the following command, but this is for the whole sample, not separated per unique `case`

```
df1$ID %in% identifier
```

And what I want as a end result is a table, with one column with each unique `case` and a second column with the number of times `ID` and `identifier` were equal.

So I want to loop/automate the process and return a similiar output like:

```
data.frame(c('a','b','c','d','e'), c(2,1,1,1,0))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `tapply()`:

```
tapply(df1$ID, df1$case, FUN = function(id) sum(id %in% identifier))

a b c d e 
2 1 1 1 0
```

but as @Jaap pointed out, you can use `aggregate()` to get a data.frame:

```
aggregate(ID ~ case, data = df1, FUN = function(id) sum(id %in% identifier))

  case ID
1    a  2
2    b  1
3    c  1
4    d  1
5    e  0
```

And if you want more grouping you can do :

```
df <- aggregate(ID ~ case+(score>1), data = df1, FUN = function(id) sum(id %in% identifier))
df[df$`score > 1`,c(1,3)]

  case ID
4    a  0
5    b  1
6    c  1
7    d  0
8    e  0
```

Comment: to get a dataframe as a result: `aggregate(ID ~ case, data = df1, FUN = function(id) sum(id %in% identifier))`

Comment: Thanks guy, and if we were to add a second constraint, whereby we also want to test if `score`>1 and obtain the sum? so a=0, b=1, c=1, d=0, e=0

Comment: Thanks @Jaap, I was battling to get `data.frame` from `tapply()`